# How to restart Sphinx search if not running

Tags: sphinx

I want to write a cron job which will check if sphinx search is running or not. If not running, it will restart. How can I do this? I am assuming I will have to use the search.pid( which has the process id) and some bash script.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tip: use a service designed for this, eg: http://mmonit.com/monit/

It will take care of the gritty details for you.

Ready to use plugins for sphinx are available
http://capitate.rubyforge.org/recipes/sphinx-monit.html

(otherwise - yes, inspect the pidfile to find the expected pid of searchd. Check if searchd is actully running on that pid. If the pid file is not found - or searchd is not running, start it. If that fails, send the administator a panicky sounding email)